# Problems with quotation marks, preg_replace or str_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Okay so, I have done stuff with regex before, but this time my brain doesn't seem to wanna work with me.

I'm trying to remove some " and some ', from some json in a string. Here's how far I got with preg_replace.

```
$string  = '"cusComment": "Direct from user input, so need to remove "double quotation marks" and \'single ones as well", "intComment": "" }}';

$blab = preg_replace('/["cusComment": "]"[", "intComment"]/', "", $string);

echo $blab;
```

This almost works for removing ", with some unwanted results.

Edit:
I guess you could do it the "other way around", and only let letters, numbers, punctation, comma, dash, underscore and white space through... still need help :)

Comment: I think you don't understand what `[]` means in regexp. It's used to match a set of characters, but you're using it for some kind of grouping.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the quotation marks in the first place? `json_encode()` escapes them properly, they shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: @Barmar I don't do json_encode this is some "json" that comes in a html email, and it's provided as is, we can't change this old weird system. So further down the line I do:
`$obj = json_decode(utf8_decode($message_nohtml_utf8),true);
foreach($obj as $key => $entry) { ..... `

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique.  It effectively works to disqualify specific matches and only return the substrings (double quotes in this case) that you want.

The following pattern only handles the tricky double quote matching with regex.  A simple call of `str_replace()` handles the single quotes because ALL of them are to be omitted.

Pattern: `/("[:,] "|^"|" \}{2})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"|\\'/`

This pattern says, disqualify the following matches:

- two double quotes that are separated by a colon or comma and space
- a double quote at the start of the line
- a double quote followed by a space and two closing curly brackets
- a single quote preceded by a slash

[Demo of Pattern & Replacement](https://regex101.com/r/HZrOmc/1)

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c550eac3e3a8e4fdd8925c03d2e370c343a1b409)) *the pattern needs an extra slash in the php implementation

```
$string  = '"cusComment": "Direct from user input, so need to remove "double quotation marks" and \'single ones as well", "intComment": "" }}';
$blab = preg_replace('/("[:,] "|^"|" \}{2})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"|\\\'/', "", $string);
echo $blab;
```

I'm not sure what further modifying you are doing to this string to prepare it, but those task may or may not be well coupled with this pattern.

If you are going to remove the trailing `}` and empty spaces, it seems logical to call `rtrim($blab,' }')`, but it is also reasonable to spare the extra function call and just extend the pattern:
`/("[:,] "|^"|"(?= \}{2}$))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"|\\'| \}{2}$/`